# Write XML Python - Special characters error in list of string

Tags: python, django, xml, jinja2

I have a list of string which I want to write in a XML file. My code looks like this :

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape   
import os

env = Environment(loader = PackageLoader(path),
                      autoescape = select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']))

list_data = ['<managedObject class="test" operation="test"/>', '<managedObject class="test" operation="test"/>']

template = env.get_template('template.xml')
output_from_parsed_template = template.render(scripts=list_data)
path = os.path.join("output_file.xml")
with open(str(path), "wb") as fh:
      fh.write(output_from_parsed_template.encode('utf-8'))
```

My template.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
{% for script in scripts %}
     {{ script }}
{% endfor %}
```

And I get the following error in the output_file.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
&lt;managedObject class=&#34;test&#34; operation=&#34;test&#34;/&gt;

&lt;managedObject class=&#34;test&#34; operation=&#34;test&#34;/&gt;
```

Do you know how to write all special characters (double quotes and inf/supp sign) in the XML ?
I'm using the same function to write a txt file and I don't have this problem.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `{{ script | safe }}` - this way Jinja puts XML/HTML as is - without converting to safer version which blocks hacker injections.

Comment: or maybe you should remove `autoescape=` to put XML/HTML as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not writing but autoescaping in Jinja.

You have to use

```
 {{ script | safe }}
```

to put XML/HTML without autoescaping.

Or remove line `autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])` from code.